# Eclipse: switch between editors keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard

Is there any keyboard shortcut like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> for switching between open editors in Eclipse except for the advertised <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>?

Is there a way to customise it?

Comment: This should probably go on stackoverflow (or superuser).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I get right you want <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd> + (<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd>)

And also you can change any shortcuts by going to Eclipse Preferences (<kbd>cmd ,</kbd>) and chose general in left side window and select key then scroll to find your desired shortcuts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Custom KeyBinding sequence example :  <kbd>CTRL + TAB</kbd>  to switch between visilble Modules or Editors **Forward** direction using Eclipse RCP.

you press <kbd>CTRL + TAB</kbd>  second  time to open
another editor and close previous editor using RCP Eclipse.

```
public class Emp_editor_open extends AbstractHandler{

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

        //Three object create in EditorInput 
        ProductEditorInput product_input=new ProductEditorInput();
        EmployeeEditorInput emp_input=new EmployeeEditorInput();
        UserEditorInput std_input = new UserEditorInput();

        IEditorReference[] editors = page.getEditorReferences();
        System.out.println("Length : "+editors.length);

        if(editors.length==0){
            //First Time or empty editors to check this condition
            try {
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Product_Editor")){
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(emp_input, EmployeeEditor.Id);
                System.out.println("Employee Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Employee_Editor")){
            System.out.println("Emp:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(std_input, UserEditor.ID);
                System.out.println("student Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(page.getActiveEditor().getTitle().equals("Student_Editor")){
            System.out.println("Product:: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                page.closeAllEditors(true);
                page.openEditor(product_input,ProductEditor.ID);
                System.out.println("product Editor open");
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Plugin.xml

---

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
        <command
                defaultHandler="rcp_demo.Toolbar.Emp_editor_open"
                id="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.emp_editor_open_cmd"
                name="Employee_Editor_open">
        </command>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
        <key
                commandId="RCP_Demo.Toolbar.emp_editor_open_cmd"
                schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
                sequence="M1+TAB">
        </key>              
    </extension>
```

> Key sequence Mapping M1 means  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>